# Hibernate_sequence table is generated

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have id column with generated strategy AUTO, I'm wondering, why MySql generate hibernate_sequence table? I supposed that hibernate will pick IDENTITY id generating strategy

```
<mapped-superclass class="com.cl.xlp.model.data.Identity">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" />
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
```

Hibernate properties

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Mysql connector version

```
version.mysql.connector>5.1.39</version.mysql.connector>
```

Mysql server version is 5.6.12

Comment: The fallback strategy for AUTO in Hibernate is SEQUENCE, but because MySQL doesn't support sequences, Hibernate simulates them using a table. Change your strategy to IDENTITY.

Answer (score 43):

The way Hibernate interprets AUTO generation type has changed starting with Hibernate version 5.0.

When using Hibernate v 4.0 and Generation Type as `AUTO`, specifically for MySql, Hibernate would choose the `IDENTITY` strategy (and thus use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature) for generating IDs for the table in question.

Starting with version 5.0 when Generation Type is selected as AUTO, Hibernate uses `SequenceStyleGenerator` regardless of the database.  In case of MySql Hibernate emulates a sequence using a table and is why you are seeing the hibernate_sequence table.  MySql doesn't support the standard sequence type natively.

References

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto
- https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/

Comment: So does that mean I need to create the hibernate_sequence table manually or is Hibernate supposed to do that for us?

Comment: I believe hibernate will create that table - assuming the DB user has proper access rights; should be easy to check - just start your app.

Answer (score 21):

If you use `strategy="AUTO"`, Hibernate will generate a table called `hibernate_sequence` to provide the next number for the `ID` sequence. You may have forgotten to add the `AutoIncrement` feature to your table's PK.

You may use generation strategy `strategy="IDENTITY"` to enforce using the `AutoIncrement` feature available in MySql and avoid creating a table.