# Hibernate Mappings results in creating addtional columns automatically - Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I was facing problem in hibernate mappings with onetomany Bidirectional.

Whenever I run application it automatically creates two columns in Primary key table as first_name and last_name.

I dont know what exact mistake. here is my code that mappings in springboot. Sorry, I m in beginner level in spring.

> TABLE persons :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Persons {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "personid")
    int PersonID;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    String LastName;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    String FirstName;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    String Address;

    @Column(name = "City")
    String City;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "persons", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Person_detail> person_detail = new ArrayList<Person_detail>();
...................
..................
}
```

> TABLE person_detail :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_detail")
public class Person_detail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    @Column(name = "Address")
    String Address;
    @Column(name = "Designation")
    String Designation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "personid")
    Persons persons;
...................
.............
}
```

> My application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/testapp


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/socket
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=roor
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

> My MySql query to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);

CREATE TABLE Person_detail (
    id int PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Address varchar(255),
    Designation varchar(50),
   person_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons(personid)
);
```

So my data at first is

[image]
[image]

**When I run Springboot application It automatically creates first_name and last_name by alterting table.**

> My logcat is:

```
2018-06-25 20:35:15.119  INFO 6576 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: alter table socket.persons add column first_name varchar(255)
Hibernate: alter table socket.persons add column last_name varchar(255)
```

My table after running project: 
[image]

Comment: Are you mixing Java config with XML config by any chance?

Comment: No. This is my entire configuration.

Comment: You have only removed getter and setter methods from your classes above right?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I assume your project is fairly small since you're just starting, try to search for first_name in all your source files.  These extra columns must come from somewhere.

Comment: That's because they Spring ignores the JPA spec and confuses the hell out of people, when they expect JPA compliant behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot configures the physical naming strategy with `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`. Which does this: For example, a `TelephoneNumber` entity is mapped to the `telephone_number` table (same goes for columns).

As you have used `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`, Spring will update the table adding new columns. In this case `first_name` for `FirstName` and `last_name` for `LastName`.

If you prefer to use Hibernate 5’s default instead, set the following property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Read [***Configure Hibernate Naming Strategy*** in **Spring Boot Reference**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy) for details.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable ans. But still project creates Hibernate_sequence as table with a row. Is the above mapping is rite?

Comment: @UserLearning: Most welcome. `hibernate_sequence` is created for maintaining `AUTO_INCREMENT`. This is normal for MySQL. And the mapping is ok. See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461283/hibernate-sequence-table-is-generated